# Xamarin.iOS share image and voice record

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I use to XF, and already implemented Xamarin.Android part. and now I'm looking for a solution on Xamarin.IOS to share 1 audio(voice record) and 1 image to WhatsApp by 1 click.

Is it possible to implement on Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91460/video-and-image-sharing-on-cross-platform

Comment: @ColeXia yeah. I read this topic, but there example with one tile type, I need to send two file